# Comma-formated numbers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers

I have following function in jQuery to format the number into comma-formatted:

```
function CommaFormattedN(amount) {

    var delimiter = ","; 
    var i = parseInt(amount);

    if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }

    i = Math.abs(i);

    var minus = '';
    if (i < 0) { minus = '-'; }

    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];

    while(n.length > 3)
    {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }

    if (n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }

    n = a.join(delimiter);

    amount = minus + n;

    return amount;

}
```

I am calling this function like this on

```
 $('.text_field1').bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){    
 var $el = $(this);
    $el.val(CommaFormattedN($el.val()));
});
```

It's working fine, but the problem is, when number of digits increase from 5, it makes nothing.  All digits are deleted and it starts again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is a bug related to sign. You are using absolute value instead of original one.
2. Your code seems to work fine, you can try debugging the way you are calling your function.

Here is your working code with minor edit ( sign related ) :
http://jsfiddle.net/qcVDc/1/

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Number.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToLocaleString) function to format a number into a locale specific format. Note that the output of the function varies with regional settings:

```
var n = parseInt("-123456789", 10);
console.log(n.toLocaleString())
// returns -123,456,789 on my computer (english-us locale)
// returns -123 456 789 for french locale
// returns -123.456.789 for german locale
// returns -123'456'789 for romansh (???) locale
```