# Create function normal number formatting?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I tried the following code but is <del>doesn't work</del> triggers an error:

```
val.reverse is not a function
```

How can I fix it?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9ysZa/

```
//I want this output: 1,455,000
function num(val){
         var result = val.reverse().join("")
                          .match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",")
                          .match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    return result     
}
alert(num('1455000'))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comma-formated numbers in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942103/comma-formated-numbers-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9ysZa/3/)

`reverse` is a method on `Array.prototype`—it works with arrays.  Since `val` is a string, you'll need to call `val.split('')` to get it into an array.

```
function num(val){
         var result = val.split('').reverse().join("")
                          .match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",")
                          .match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    return result     
}
alert(num('1455000'));
```

Which alerts the results you're looking for.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, it looks like you want to run this on the **number** 1455000 rather than the **string** '1455000'.  If so, adding a `toString` call before `split()` will work (and will work on both strings **and numbers).

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ysZa/5/)

Comment: I get in myself code this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object 1455000 has no method 'split'` how is fix it?

Comment: Add a `toString()` for safety: `var result = val.toString().split("").reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").split("").reverse().join("");`

Comment: @JulianD. - yep - was typing that as you wrote you comment.