# regular express for number formatting

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not an expert on regex and I need some help on formatting numbers.

This is what I have:

```
TheNumber = TheNumber.toString().split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g).join(",");
```

Basically, I want TheNumber to be formatted with commas to separate thousands and up to 3 decimal precision with a dot to indicate decimal if there are decimals. It should also work with negative numbers.

I'm not far only that for the moment

```
3234234.223512 becomes 3,234,234.223,512
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671672/create-function-normal-number-formatting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Javascript library [accounting.js](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/accounting.js/#download)

As mentioned in description.
Accounting.js is a tiny JavaScript library for number, money and currency formatting, with optional excel-style column rendering (to line up symbols and decimals). It's lightweight, fully localisable and has zero dependencies.

It does the same as your requirements and even a little more.

Comment: ok thanks; however, I'm not looking for a plug-in that adds overhead. I'm just looking to fix my regex and do the formatting in one line of code.

Comment: K on searching I found some links. Just see if they might be useful. [Javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/twodec.shtml?), [Javascriptbank](http://www.javascriptbank.com/currency-format-script.html) and [Codingforums](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-221373.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd solve the problem in two pieces rather than a single regular expression.  In particular, I'd:

1. remove the decimal point and any following numbers from the string first
2. User your reg exp (minus the decimal part) to add commas to the first part
3. concatenate back the removed decimal point